# V8: Fatal error: CHECK(V8::ArrayBufferAllocator() != NULL) failed

Tags: javascript, v8

I get this error when I try to run some JS code ([this](http://pastebin.com/XesBSstJ) + [this](http://pastebin.com/0VawRb16)) with V8 (tried master from two weaks ago, 3.23.17, 3.24.40, 3.25.5; 3.23.0 doesn't work anymore because of API changes):

```
#
# Fatal error in ..\..\src\runtime.cc, line 785
# CHECK(V8::ArrayBufferAllocator() != NULL) failed
#
```

A lot of other JS code has worked already, so I wonder what the problem is.

It's on Win8 with a x64 build. V8 has been build just as described in the official docs (using gyp + MSVC 2012). I don't think that there was a problem because it worked fine already with most other JS code.

I think that there might be an issue with V8 itself, but not sure...

I also asked on the mailing-list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/BC-yrxSl3iI).

---

Some C++ code, but I don't think that there is a problem with it because it worked fine with other JS code:

```
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <v8.h>


// Create a new isolate (completely isolated JS VM).
struct V8Isolate : boost::noncopyable {
    v8::Isolate* isolate;
    V8Isolate() : isolate(v8::Isolate::New()) {}
    ~V8Isolate() { isolate->Dispose(); }
    operator v8::Isolate*() { return isolate; }
    v8::Isolate* operator->() { return isolate; }
};

struct ReturnType {
    std::string err; // non-empty if there is an error

    ReturnType(bool success) {
        assert(success);
    }
    ReturnType(const std::string& _err) : err(_err) {
        assert(!err.empty());
    }
    ReturnType(const char* _err) : err(_err) {
        assert(!err.empty());
    }

    operator bool() const { return err.empty(); }
};

#define CHECK_RETURN(cmd) { ReturnType ret = (cmd); if(!ret) return ret; }

using namespace std;
using namespace v8;

ReturnType readFile(const std::string& filename, std::string& res) {
    res = "";

    FILE* f = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");
    if(!f) return "File '" + filename + "' cannot be opened";

    while(!feof(f) && !ferror(f)) {
        char buffer[1024 * 8];
        size_t s = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), f);
        if(s > 0)
            res.append(buffer, buffer + s);
    }

    auto err = ferror(f);
    fclose(f);

    if(err)
        return "Error while reading file '" + filename + "'";

    return true;
}



ReturnType execJsFile(const std::string& jsSourceDir, const std::string& extfilename) {
    v8::TryCatch try_catch;

    std::string sourceStr;
    CHECK_RETURN(readFile(jsSourceDir + "/" + extfilename, sourceStr));

    Local<String> origin = String::NewFromUtf8(Isolate::GetCurrent(), &extfilename[0], String::kNormalString, (int)extfilename.size());
    Local<String> source = String::NewFromUtf8(Isolate::GetCurrent(), &sourceStr[0], String::kNormalString, (int)sourceStr.size());

    Local<v8::Script> script = Script::Compile(source, origin);
    if(script.IsEmpty()) {
        assert(try_catch.HasCaught());
        return "JS compile failed: " + jsObjToString(try_catch.Exception());
    }

    // Run the script to setup its environment
    Local<Value> result = script->Run();
    if(result.IsEmpty()) {
        assert(try_catch.HasCaught());
        return "JS script execution failed: " + jsReportExceptionToString(Isolate::GetCurrent(), &try_catch);
    }

    return true;
}


ReturnType loadJsGit() {
    V8Isolate isolate;
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolateScope(isolate);
    HandleScope handleScope(isolate);
    Handle<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);
    Context::Scope contextScope(context);
    auto globalObj = context->Global();

    CHECK_RETURN(execJsFile(".", "global.js"));
    CHECK_RETURN(execJsFile(".", "jsgit.js"));

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ReturnType ret = loadJsGit();
    if(!ret) cout << "error: " << ret.err << endl;
}
```

Comment: It’s very hard to say without knowing what you’re attempting here or how you’re trying to run it, or seeing any of your code.

Comment: It's a very long code and it absolutely wont help (because with other code, I don't get the error). But [here](http://pastebin.com/0VawRb16) you go.

Comment: I'd argue that such a question is better asked in a V8 support group.

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? Wait, is this Node, or a client-side Node-like environment to do interesting things with? (And if it’s the latter… you’re crashing browser JavaScript? That’d be something.) If you’re running it in V8, is your V8 up to date? Is it stable?

Comment: @minitech: No, it's just V8. It was from a Git checkout two weeks ago - just followed [this](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/UsingGit) and [this](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP).

Comment: Where does `window` come from? Are you using something to… simulate a browser? And does it seem like you’re running out of memory?

Comment: @Albert: Ah, okay. Try a stable version, assuming you checked out a development branch.

Comment: @minitech: `window` is defined [here](http://pastebin.com/XesBSstJ). I'm not running out of memory.

Comment: @minitech: How do I know what a stable version is? I tried tag 3.25.5 now but I still get the same crash.

Comment: Works fine for me, running on Node. Try v8 3.23.17.13, too.

Comment: @minitech: That tag doesn't exist in Git. What's its ref? I tried 3.23.17 and also get the same crash. I'm on Win8 and using a x64 build, if that matters.

Comment: I’d guessed as much from the backslashes, and that’s unfamiliar territory for me – sorry. Are you building V8 in MinGW/Cygwin? Are you running it in the same environment?

Comment: I just followed the official introduction, i.e. I used gyp to create the MSVC solution and then MSVC to build it. I ran gyp however in Cygwin but I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: @SergeS, ...: Care to explain? It already contains the full example. Also, as I guessed, it's all obsolete information, as you can see in the answer. Please don't abuse StackOverflow by voting to close questions you simply don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initialize array buffer allocator.

Use malloc, for example:

```
class MallocArrayBufferAllocator : public v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator {
public:
  virtual void* Allocate(size_t length) { return malloc(length); }
  virtual void* AllocateUninitialized(size_t length) { return malloc(length); }
  virtual void Free(void* data, size_t length) { free(data); }
};
```

Initialize:

```
v8::V8::SetArrayBufferAllocator(new MallocArrayBufferAllocator);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! :) The [embedder guide](https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started) really should have documented this. Your answer was almost at the same time as I got the same answer on the mailing-list. :)

Comment: Yeah, the guide is a bit outdated. :)